# How to use Systems Manager `run command`

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ssm

I've been going through the steps on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-setting-up.html guide but can't get to show `Managed Instances` on the Systems Manager.

I've been trying anything:

1. creating a role and attach it
2. letting the Systems Manager wizard create the role and attach it
3. creating the role and creating the EC2 instance afterwards

I don't know what else to do. Any thoughts or maybe link to a guide?

Comment: Do your instances have internet access?

Comment: @Marcin, they don't have Internet Access. And that actually solves the problem, as I marked on John's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are saying that the Amazon EC2 instances are not listed in the Systems Manager console. This happens when the Agent installed on the instance is not able to 'register' with the AWS service.

Some things to check:

- Confirm that the **Systems Manager Agent is installed**. It is installed by default on Amazon Linux 2 AMIs.
- Confirm that the instance has **outbound access to AWS**. If the instance is in a private subnet, it either needs a NAT Gateway to reach the Internet, or a VPC Endpoint for Systems Manager.
- Confirm that the instance has been **assigned an IAM Role** that has the `AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore` policy

Comment: The **outbound access** was the thing. But what bothers me is that I was trying to use the *Run Command* to check if an *internal* EC2 instance was reaching the internet. When I say "internal" I mean "connected to a subnet that has no internet access". I think I'll post another question for that specific use case.